# Using select scoped value in insert statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Note: I'm building a practice project where my trainer has forbid me to parameterize. I am aware of the security risks, but the site will not be deployed. I'm using a select scope_identity method to grab an auto-incremented value from the SubmissionId column of my table Submissions.

I want to insert that value into two other tables; I've got newSubID declared as a var and I use it in the insert statements, but I get the error message

> The name "newSubID" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

What am I missing here?

Here's my code:

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    String subQuery = "INSERT INTO Submission (Coverage, CurrentCoverage, PrimEx, Retention, EffectiveDate, Commission, Premium, Comments) VALUES ('" + TbCoverage.Text + "','" + TbCurrentCoverage.Text + "','" + TbPrimEx.Text + "','" + TbRetention.Text + "','" + TbEffectiveDate.Text + "','" + TbCommission.Text + "','" + TbPremium.Text + "','" + TbComments.Text + "')"
        + "SELECT CAST (SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int)";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand subCmd = new SqlCommand(subQuery, sqlConn);

        using (subCmd)
        {
            subCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var newSubID = (Int32)subCmd.ExecuteScalar();

            String custQuery = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustId, CustName, SicNaic, CustAdd, CustCity, CustState, CustZip, SubId) VALUES ('" + TbCustId.Text + "', '" + TbCustName.Text + "', '" + RblSicNaic.SelectedItem + "', '" + TbCustAddress.Text + "', '" + TbCustCity.Text + "', '" + DdlCustState.SelectedItem + "', '" + TbCustZip.Text + "', newSubID)";
            String broQuery = "INSERT INTO Broker (BroId, BroName, BroAdd, BroCity, BroState, BroZip, EntityType, SubId) VALUES ('" + TbBroId.Text + "', '" + TbBroName.Text + "', '" + TbBroAddress.Text + "', '" + TbBroCity.Text + "', '" + DdlBroState.SelectedItem + "', '" + TbBroZip.Text + "', '" + DdlEntity.SelectedItem + "', newSubID)";
            SqlCommand custCmd = new SqlCommand(custQuery, sqlConn);
            SqlCommand broCmd = new SqlCommand(broQuery, sqlConn);
            using (custCmd)
            using (broCmd)
            {
                custCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                broCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("~/View.aspx?ProductId=" + newSubID);
            }
```

This is called up on the next page like so (I have left the errors as they are in the interest of helping whomever may need to see the problem and solutions, which are listed in answers below):

```
string x = Request.QueryString["SubmissionId"];
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string editCustQuery = "SELECT CustName, SicNaic, CustCity, CustAdd, CustState, CustZip FROM Customer WHERE SubId =" + x;
using (SqlConnection editConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    editConn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand CustCommand = new SqlCommand(editCustQuery, editConn))
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = CustCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        LblCustName.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        LblSicNaic.Text = dr.GetString(1);
        LblCustCity.Text = dr.GetString(2);
        LblCustAddress.Text = dr.GetString(3);
        LblCustState.Text = dr.GetString(4);
        LblCustZip.Text = dr.GetInt32(5).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: @ibram, won't going out of scope (which is the correct term for closing that block of code w/ the curly brace, I think) close the reader automatically?

Comment: you should be wearing a helmet. It won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not concatenating the newSubID into the custQuery / btoQuery SQL statements, but instead your using the literal text "newSubID" in the statement which is invalid here as it will assume "newSubID" is a column name.

i.e.

```
String custQuery = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustId, CustName, SicNaic, CustAdd, CustCity,
    CustState, CustZip, SubId) 
VALUES ('" + TbCustId.Text + "', '" + TbCustName.Text + "', '" + RblSicNaic.SelectedItem +   
    "', '" + TbCustAddress.Text + "', '" + TbCustCity.Text + "', '" + 
    DdlCustState.SelectedItem + "', '" + TbCustZip.Text + "'," + 
    newSubID.toString() + ")";
```

Of course, I'm only giving an answer that uses dynamic SQL like this because of your disclaimer and is not what I'd do in real life!

Comment: Of course. Many thanks, @Ada. If you don't mind a follow-up question, does my redirect line look right to you, or do I need to concatenate that as well? I'm throwing an error on the redirect page.

Comment: @Brazos - Response.Redirect("~/View.aspx?ProductId=" + newSubID.toString()) - if View.aspx then errors when it loads, then you have an error in that page which I can't tell without seeing that

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'm using this 
'string x = Request.QueryString["SubmissionId"];
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string editCustQuery = "SELECT CustName, SicNaic, CustCity, CustAdd, CustState, CustZip FROM Customer WHERE SubId =" + x;'

to call up the right row, and then a datareader to display. I'm pretty sure the data reader's fine. Is there another glaringly obvious issue with my request query?

Comment: @Brazos - assuming SubId is an INTEGER in the DB, that looks OK assuming x variable does contain a value (i.e. Request.QueryString["SubmissionId"] does give you a value).

Comment: @Ada, yes, SubId is an INT in the DB. yet another silly question, but how would I determine whether x contains a value? SubId is auto-incremented in the Submission table, so I didn't insert anything into that column in the insert command. The error message I get is an "incorrect syntax near '=' on the SqlDataReader dr = CustCommand.ExecuteReader(); line.

Comment: Temporarily add in: Response.Write(editCustQuery); Response.End();  before executing the query to get it to write out what the query it's executing is. That'll show you if something is missing (e.g. x). If not, best you start a new question.

Comment: Excuse me while I search the thesaurus for synonyms meaning thank you. The response line showed me I was calling a null value for submissionId, which led me to find that my redirect address still contained an old value, productId. Facepalm. All is well again, supercoders. Many thanks to both you, @Ada, and you, @ibram.

Answer (score 2):

1. Answer of AdaTheDev is correct.
2. I think you have another issue. If you do ExecuteNonQuery and then ExecuteScalar with the same command, you'll insert twice. Use an out-parameter for your scope_id and call only exenonquery or call just exescalar.

   ```
           //subCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           var newSubID = (Int32)subCmd.ExecuteScalar();
   ```

Comment: Thanks, @ibram. This may be a stupid question, but if I toss out the exenonquery, will I still be inserting all the other values in the command, or just calling up the value with the execscalar?

Comment: All your sql code will be done if it is in one sequence, like yours.